# Swift Combine Not Receiving Published Values

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am working on a project that is using Combine to get updates from Firebase Firestore. I have a StockListView, a StockListCellView, and a StockDetailView that I want updates to be registered in.

The StockListView holds StockListCellViews which push StockDetailsViews onto the stack.  Each view also has a corresponding ViewModel where I am working with Combine.

My trouble is my StockDetailView is not receiving the updates from Combine and I can't see why. Below is a simplified version of the code for each view and viewModel. I think this has something to do with how I am assigning in the StockDetailViewModel but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

**StockListViewModel - Works Great**

```
class StockListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stockRepository = StockRepository()
    @Published var stockListCellViewModels = [StockListCellViewModel]()

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        stockRepository.$stocks.map { stocks in
            stocks.map { stock in
                StockListCellViewModel(stockDetailViewModel: StockDetailViewModel(stock: stock))
            }
        }
        .assign(to: \.stockListCellViewModels, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

**StockListView - Works Great**

```
struct StockListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var stockRepository = StockRepository()
    @ObservedObject var stockListVM = StockListViewModel()
        
    var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(stockListVM.stockListCellViewModels) { stockListCellVM in
                            NavigationLink(destination: StockDetailView(stockDetailVM: stockListCellVM.stockDetailViewModel)) {
                                StockListCell(stockListVM: stockListVM, stockListCellVM: stockListCellVM)
                            }
                    }
                } // List
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("stock")
        } // NavigationView
    } // View
}
```

**StockListCellViewModel - Works Great**

```
class StockListCellViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: String = ""
    @Published var stockDetailViewModel: StockDetailViewModel
    @Published var stock: Stock

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(stockDetailViewModel: StockDetailViewModel) {
        self.stockDetailViewModel = stockDetailViewModel
        self.stock = stockDetailViewModel.stock

        stockDetailViewModel.$stock.compactMap { stock in
            stock.id
        }
        .assign(to: \.id, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)

        stockDetailViewModel.$stock.map { stock in
            StockDetailViewModel(stock: stock)
        }
        .assign(to: \.stockDetailViewModel, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

**StockListCellView - Works Great**

```
struct StockListCell: View {
    @ObservedObject var stockListVM: StockListViewModel
    @ObservedObject var stockListCellVM: StockListCellViewModel

    var body: some View {
                Text(stockListCellVM.stock.ticker)
    }
}
```

**StockDetailViewModel - Not Updating**

```
class StockDetailViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: String = ""
    @Published var stock: Stock
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(stock: Stock) {
        self.stock = stock
        self.chartColor = UIColor()

        $stock.compactMap { stock in
            stock.id
        }
        .assign(to: \.id, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

**StockDetailView - Not Updating**

```
struct StockDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var stockDetailVM: StockDetailViewModel

    var body: some View {
                    Text(stockDetailVM.stock.ticker)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small suggestion, it would be best to isolate the bare minimum code necessary to replicate the problem. Please don't post your entire project, simplify it into a smaller example others can easily understand.

Comment: Thank you @user1046037. I've stripped the code down to a simpler form. I appreciate the advice.

Comment: To simplify the problem, your model gets the data but the View doesn't react to the data?

Comment: Exactly, The StockDetailView is not reacting. The StockListCellView does and I don't see why one would and the other would not.

Comment: `StockDetailView` depends on `StockDetailViewModel`, if the value of the model changes it would react. If a property of a class changes it does not mean the class has changed (For a value type like struct, if any of it's properties changes, then it means the value has changed).

Comment: There are 2 possible solutions, one is to make the view depend on the exact property of the model (in your case ticker). Or when the ticker changes ensure you execute `objectWillChange.send()`. I personally prefer option1 as it is better to define the precise dependancy instead the dependancy on the entire model.

Comment: I like solution 1 as well. I suppose I am not understanding how to do that? Do I connect the StockListCellViewModel directly to the StockRepository like I did in StockListViewModel? I'm initializing StockListCellViewModel with a StockDetailViewModel and then using the stockDetailViewModel to map. Would I just map over the repository? I supposed that would through my reference off?

Comment: What is the data type of ticker? I am assuming it is a `Int` / `Double`, just make `ticker` as `@Published` property in `StockDetailViewModel`.  See if that fixes the problem in `StockDetailView`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. In the Cell view I’m publishing Stock and that updates all the properties of the stock. I don’t see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me the better part of two weeks to solve and I wanted to post it here for anyone experiencing the same issue I had. I rebuilt a simple example to make things easier to understand. Here is what the app does.

1. Connects to a Firestore database and starts a SnapShootListener to collect Note objects.
2. Once collected it stores the Notes, in an array of Note objects.
3. This array of notes is built into a List of notes.
4. Each note progresses to a NoteDetailView.

What I expected to happen was that as a Note was updated on the server, I would see the note update in real-time in the List and in the DetailView. My problem was that I could only see live updates in the List.

The reason for this is because you cannot bind a data element from a ForEach loop. This means that any updates made on the server never make it to the DetailView.

To solve this I introduced EnvironmentObjects and created DetailViews by passing the index of the Note to be shown in the DetailView to the DetailView. This allowed me to access the correct Note in the DetailView. The code below shows how this was done. NOTE: I did not added a NoteDetailViewModel.swift to simplify things.

**<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>App.swift**

```
   @main
struct ToDoSwiftUITutorialApp: App {
    // 1. An @StateObject was created for the NoteRepository connected to Firestore.
    @StateObject private var noteRepository = NoteRepository()
    
    // Firebase
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously()
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(noteRepository) // noteRepository was added to ContentView as an EnvironmentObject.
        }
    }
}
```

**NoteRepository.swift**

```
    class NoteRepository: ObservableObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    // Publishing the array of Note object received from Firestore.
    @Published var notes = [Note]()
    
    init() {
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        db.collection("notes").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                self.notes = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                    do {
                        let x = try document.data(as: Note.self)
                        return x
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NoteListView.swift**

```
    struct NoteListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var noteListViewModel = NoteListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(noteListViewModel.noteCellViewModels.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        NavigationLink(destination: NoteDetailView(index: index).environmentObject(self.noteListViewModel)) {
                            NoteCellView(noteCellViewModel: noteListViewModel.noteCellViewModels[index])
                            } // NavigationLink
                    } // ForEach
                }// List
            .navigationBarTitle("Notes")
        } // NavigationView
    }
}
```

**NoteListViewModel.swift**

```
    class NoteListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var noteRepository = NoteRepository()
    @Published var noteCellViewModels = [NoteCellViewModel]()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        noteRepository.$notes.map { notes in
            notes.map { note in
                NoteCellViewModel(note: note)
            }
        }
        .assign(to: \.noteCellViewModels, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

**NoteCellView.swift**

```
    struct NoteCellView: View {
    @ObservedObject var noteCellViewModel: NoteCellViewModel
        
    var body: some View {
        Text(noteCellViewModel.note.note)
    }
}
```

**NoteCellViewModel.swift**

```
    class NoteCellViewModel: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: String = ""
    @Published var note: Note
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(note: Note) {
        self.note = note
        
        $note.compactMap { note in
            note.id
        }
        .assign(to: \.id, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

**NoteDetailView.swift**

```
    struct NoteDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var noteRepository: NoteRepository
    var index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(noteRepository.notes[index].note)
    }
}
```